# How to create loading bar for asset bundles on Unity (without changing scene)?

Tags: unity, assets, coroutines

So from [the official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync.html) and [unity forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1390808/how-to-preload-assets-with-progress-bar.html) now I know that there's async version of LoadFromFile (that I also will probably call `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle` later for updated asset). Now the problem is where can I call it, and how to get the `.progress` value, converting from this:

```
public AssetManager()
{
    if (!useAssetBundle) return;
    foreach (var bundle_name in bundle_names)
    {
        var full_path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Bundle/", bundle_name);
        var bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(full_path);
        if (bundle == null) LogHelper.Critical("Failed to load AssetBundle {0}", full_path);
        bundles[bundle_name] = bundle;
    }
}
```

To this (that obviously wrong):

```
private List<AssetBundleCreateRequest> loadPro = new List<AssetBundleCreateRequest>();

private IEnumerator<AssetBundle> _loadOneAssetBundle(string full_path)
{
    var creq = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(full_path);
    loadPro.Add(creq);
    yield return creq.assetBundle;
}

public AssetManager(MonoBehaviour parent)
{
    if (!useAssetBundle) return;
    foreach (var bundle_name in bundle_names)
    {
        var full_path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Bundle/", bundle_name);
        var bundle = parent.StartCoroutine(_loadOneAssetBundle(full_path)).assetBundle; // NOPE T_T)
        if (bundle == null) LogHelper.Critical("Failed to load AssetBundle {0}", full_path);
        bundles[bundle_name] = bundle; // NOPE 'n')
    }
}

public void Update()
{
    var progress = 0f;
    foreach (var pro in loadPro)
    {
        progress += pro.progress;
    }
    LogHelper.Debug("Progress %f",progress);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, when you start a coroutine, your execution doesn't block and wait for it to finish. It continues to the next line immediately.

So, the problems in your code are:

```
var bundle = parent.StartCoroutine(_loadOneAssetBundle(full_path)).assetBundle;
```

A) StartCoroutine just starts a Coroutine - it doesn't load your asset bundle for you (it doesn't know what an AssetBundle is!) so you can't fetch a reference to your bundle out of it like this.

```
if (bundle == null) LogHelper.Critical("Failed to load AssetBundle {0}", full_path);
bundles[bundle_name] = bundle;
```

B) Even if you could, the Coroutine has only just started at this point. The load hasn't had a chance to complete yet, so you're trying to grab your bundle too early.

Instead, you want to read your AssetBundle *after* the load has finished *inside your Coroutine*. This adapted straight from the [documentation for LoadFromFileAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync.html):

```
IEnumerator LoadAssetBundleFromPath(string path)
{
    var bundleLoadRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);

    // Track progress while it's loading.
    loadProgress.Add(bundleLoadRequest);

    // Wait until the load has finished.
    yield return bundleLoadRequest;

    // Done tracking.
    loadProgress.Remove(bundleLoadRequest);

    // NOW it's safe to grab the bundle, since we waited for it to load.
    var myLoadedAssetBundle = bundleLoadRequest.assetBundle;
    if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
        yield break;
    }

    // Put your code that stores / uses the AssetBundle here.
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got it work too from reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030894